# How can I transform a "natural join" to yii2 Active query?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, relational-database

How can I transform this query to an ActiveQuery in yii2?

```
SELECT * from table1 natural join table2 natural join table3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming  the table Table1 is associated  to the model class Model1  and that the column for natueal join  is named  id

```
     $model =  Model1::find()
      ->innerJoin('Table2', 'table1.id = Table2.id' )
      ->innerJoin('Table3', 'table1.id = Table3.id' )
      ->all();
```